# Time picker format

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I am using time picker in my Android project. But it shows 8.1 instead of 8.01. I am using code:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
        timerFlag = true;
        minuteP = minute;
        hourP = hour;
        flagData.setTimePicker(timerFlag);
        setTime(timePicker, hour, minute);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to check if minute is less than 10.Code is given below...

```
    String minuteFormatter = "";
    if (minute < 10) {
        minuteFormatter = "0" + minute;
    } else {
        minuteFormatter = String.valueOf(minute);
    }
    StringBuilder Time = new StringBuilder().append(hour).append(" : ")
            .append(minuteFormatter);
```

Answer (score 1):

> String.format("%02d:%02d",hour,minute)